# split string by comma in sql query

Tags: sql, split

split string by comma in SQL and store them as split_item1, split_item2
and

```
select column_name from table-name where column_name = 'split_item1' or split_item2'
```

please post the correct syntax for this

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using `SQL Server`, you need to concatenate `,` from both sides of the column so you can match the value you are searching.

```
SELECT  *
FROM    TableName
WHERE   ',' + csvColumn + ',' LIKE '%,' + 'split_item1' + ',%' OR
        ',' + csvColumn + ',' LIKE '%,' + 'split_item2' + ',%'
```

Concatenation symbol differs on every dbms, `CONCAT()` for MySQL, `||` for Oracle.

- [SQLFiddle Demo for SQL Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e104c/2)
- [SQLFiddle Demo for MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eab64/3)
- [SQLFiddle Demo for Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/16f8b/2)

Comment: i have string in a column1 that is '001,002,003,...' and '022' is the corresponding column i.e. column2
i need to split the string according to comma separated value into 001 002 003 so that whenever i give the value 001 or 002 or 003 it should return '022' column2
i.e. 
select column2 from table_name where column1 like 001 or 002 or 003

Answer (score 0):

You can use the follow code (created for sqlserver).

```
Create Function FUN_STRING_SPLIT(@text varchar(max), @separator varchar(10))
Returns @Result Table 
(
   POSITION INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, VALUE VARCHAR(max) 
)
As 
Begin
    Declare @ini int = 1, @end int = 0

    While @end <= LEN(@text)
    Begin
        if @end > 0 set @ini = @end + LEN(@separator)
        if @ini > 0 set @end = CHARINDEX(@separator, @text, @ini)
        if @end = 0 set @end = LEN(@text) + 1

        Insert Into @Result (VALUE) Values (SUBSTRING(@text,@ini,@end - @ini))
    End
    Return
End
```

Then use like:

```
Select * From FUN_STRING_SPLIT('Word1,Word2,Word2,Etc..', ',');
```

Answer (score 0):

select * from fromSplitStringSep('Word1 wordr2 word3',' ')

```
CREATE function [dbo].[SplitStringSep] 
    (
        @str nvarchar(4000), 
        @separator char(1)
    )
    returns table
    AS
    return (
        with tokens(p, a, b) AS (
            select 
                1, 
                1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str)
            union all
            select
                p + 1, 
                b + 1, 
                charindex(@separator, @str, b + 1)
            from tokens
            where b > 0
        )
        select
            p-1 zeroBasedOccurance,
            substring(
                @str, 
                a, 
                case when b > 0 then b-a ELSE 4000 end) 
            AS s
        from tokens
      )
```